# Garbage text in serial monitor from Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a problem with my brand new *Arduino*, it seems that
no matter what I print with

```
Serial.println()
```

be it numbers, strings or anything else, I get garbage 
on the *Arduino* serial monitor:

[image]

Not even the simplest *hello world* program works.

Could you help me identify the problem and solve it?

Comment: i try DEC but doesnt work

Comment: this http://i.hizliresim.com/m3jzR8.png

Comment: doesnt work :( http://i.hizliresim.com/37BaGr.png

Comment: Do you have anything connected to pins TX and RX (aka pin 0 and 1)?

Comment: Yes I did not write the program if it did not exist

Comment: Sorry my english is bad. I got all the connections right. If it was wrong I could not program

Comment: I did not do anything. I already bought it 1 day ago

Comment: okay thank you i try

Comment: my second arduino not print garbage but this clone arduino

Comment: It is an *arduino clone*? that explains a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution :)
I wrote a test program and found a working baud-rate at 600.

[image]

My test program:

```cpp
long baudrates[] = {600,1200,2400,4800,9600,14400,19200,28800,38400,56000,57600,115200,128000,256000};
unsigned char baudcounter = 0;
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
 // initialize serial communication
 Serial.begin(baudrates[baudcounter]);
}
// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
 Serial.println();
 Serial.println(baudrates[baudcounter]);
 Serial.println(" !\"#$%&amp;'()*+,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~");
 Serial.println();
 baudcounter++;
 baudcounter %= sizeof(baudrates)/sizeof(long);
 delay(1000); // delay 
 Serial.begin(baudrates[baudcounter]); // switch baudrate
}
```